# Protecting my Google Site with OAuth

Tags: oauth, google-sites

I've set up a new site with Google Sites. I'm pretty sure there are some options to protect my site with login and to integrate with OAuth but I cannot find the right settings page. Furthermore, I'm missing the "groups" tab where I can set up mailing lists. Do I need a special Google account to access such features?

Answer (score 1):

You can site level and page level protection from within the google site. You do not need OAuth to do that. Visitors do not need to do a separate login protection for your site.

When entering the site in edit mode -> **more** -> **manage site** 
**Sharing and permissions**

From here you can set:
 
- if the site is publicly visible or only to people you want them to visit the site.
- If you turn page level permissions *on* you can do the same for each individual page.

The page the user does not have permission to visit, simply does not show up in the menus.